# Why number of contributions in GitHub decrease?

Tags: github

We can see our contributions to some repo in

https://github.com/some-organization/some-repo/graphs/contributors

I had over 1000 contributions to a repo, but today when I see that page,
I had only recent 40 contributions.

The same thing happens in other repos of the same organization.

I thoght that contributions in a repo never decrease. But it does.

What is happening? Will my contributions come back?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not GitHub customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. If you delete email address you used to make commits from GitHub, the connected contributions to these commits disappear.

I can fix this by re-adding the email address to GitHub.